# C# object instance wont return values

Tags: c#

Currently working on a text based GTA type game as part of a project. Having difficulty understand how C# handles classes/objects/values from one file to another..

In my main Program.cs file I have:

```
public static Data CreatePlayer()
{
  //INIT PLAYER INSTANCE (playername, credits, playerhealth, armourhealth, wantedlevel, 
  currentlocation)
  Data Player = new Data("PLAYER1", 100, 10, 0, 0, "DOWNTOWN");
   
  return Player;
            
}
```

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var Player = CreatePlayer();
  Data.Stats(Player);
}
```

And in my Data.cs file i have:

```
public class Data
{
        
        //create private fields(vars)
        private string playername;
        private uint credits;
        private uint playerhealth;
        private uint armourhealth;
        private uint wantedlevel;
        private string currentlocation;
        

        //create public props(values)
        public string PLAYER_NAME
        { get; set; }

        public uint CREDITS
        { get; set; }

        public uint PLAYER_HEALTH
        { get; set; }

        public uint ARMOUR_HEALTH
        { get; set; }

        public uint WANTED_LEVEL
        { get; set; }

        public string CURRENT_LOCATION
        { get; set; }

        
        //create class constructor and params
        public Data(string playername, uint credits, uint playerhealth, uint armourhealth, uint wantedlevel, string currentlocation)
        {
            this.playername = PLAYER_NAME;
            this.credits = CREDITS;
            this.playerhealth = PLAYER_HEALTH;
            this.armourhealth = ARMOUR_HEALTH;
            this.wantedlevel = WANTED_LEVEL;
            this.currentlocation = CURRENT_LOCATION;
        }

        public static void Stats(Object player)
        {
            Type t = player.GetType();
            PropertyInfo[] props = t.GetProperties();
            
            foreach (var prop in props)
                if (prop.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0)
                {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", prop.Name, prop.GetValue(player));
                Console.WriteLine("---------------------");
                }
                
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("   {0} ({1}): <Indexed>", prop.Name, 
                    prop.PropertyType.Name);
                }
        }
```

These 2 files do not seem to communicate to eachother. I get no errors in the console, but all the values when Data.Stats() is called on the Player object come back as 0 if a uint or blank if a string.

Comment: Don't mix properties and fields. You assign values to _fields_, but expect to read them from completely unrelated _properties_.

Comment: Perhaps you need to invert the lines in the Data constructor. You want to write _this.PLAYER_NAME = playername;_ etc... And, yes the _private_ fields are not needed at all and just confusing here

Answer (score 1):

You never assign a value to the public properties of `Data`, which is why they always return their default values of zero for an `unit` and `null` for `string`.

Your `Data` class seems half setup for private fields to be the backing values for the public properties, but you're not using them. For example:

`private string playername;`

`public string PLAYER_NAME { get; set; }`

The public property `PLAYER_NAME` is not using `playername` here. It will create its own backing field automatically during compilation. The `get` and `set` are automatically implemented to use that backing field. If you wanted to use your own, the property would need to look like this:

```
public string PLAYER_NAME {
    get {
        return playername;
    }
    set {
        playername = value;
    }
}
```

However, in your case having your own backing fields isn't necessary. You can just assign directly to the public properties in the constructor and let it handle the backing fields, and remove your own. It's clearer that way and less code. Generally having your own backing fields is only necessary when you need more complex logic in the property getters and setters.